# How to get semi-transparent view while child views are normal

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController derived class and what I'd like to do is have a subview that is not transparent while its parent view (the main UIViewController.view) has 50% transparency.

On the controller classes' viewDidLoad, I set the alpha value of the view and subview. However, what I'm seeing is that both the base view and the subview are both semi-transparent. Is there a way to not have this happen?

```
// Class declaration
@interface MyViewControllerClass : UIViewController
{ }
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView  *contentView;
@end

// Class implementation
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // I want the main view to be a transparent overlay
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.view setAlpha:0.5];

    // This is the subview I want to look normal
    [self.contentView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.contentView setOpaque:NO];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You need to arrange your views in another way to get the effect you desire. Try adding another UIView to the main view and set its transparency to 50% instead. That way your other items can stay on the main view and not be affected.

Comment: Thanks. I created a separate overlay view and that works as intended.